# Bash: Too many arguments

Tags: bash, arguments

I've coded the following script to add users from a text file. It works, but I'm getting an error that says "too many arguments"; what is the problem?

```
#!/bin/bash

file=users.csv

while IFS="," read USRNM DOB SCH PRG PST ENROLSTAT ; do

if [ $ENROLSTAT == Complete ] ;
then
useradd $USRNM -p $DOB

else

echo "User $USRNM is not fully enrolled"
fi

done < $file

#cat users.csv | head -n 2 | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Please post code here, since after image disappears the question will remain uncomplete and useless.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to post the source rather than a picture of the source?

Comment: So sorry this is coursework material, the anti-plagiarism software would catch it and i get low marks

Comment: The code is from another site: daniweb

Comment: no is not i coded the script, i was opening another site that solves the argument error  but it is of no help

Comment: @LatinUnit It is not relevant for our community. We need complete question to remain. Reformulate your code and post it.

Answer (score 10):

Use quotes. Liberally.

```
if [ "$ENROLSTAT" = Complete ]
```

(It's a single equal sign, too.)  My greatest problem in shell programming is always hidden spaces.  It's one of the reasons I write so much in Perl, and why, in Perl, I tell everyone on my team to *avoid the shell* whenever running external programs.  There is just so much power in the shell, with so many little things that can trip you up, that I avoid it where possible.  (And not where not possible.)

Comment: Thanks I cant believe it was the quotes, ill keep this in mind

Comment: After you answered this guy ran away.. so not it's your responsibility to add code...

Comment: Btw as you can see in the shell, it is also reading from the first line and is showing user full name is not fully supported.

i Experimented on the last line on the script which is commented out
but i cant seem to merge it with the script above

Comment: man whats wrong in this place? so much drama for a little help delete my question then :S

Comment: It is the part "Enrol Status" of the first line which generates the error message. Because after string substitution `[ Enrol Status == complete ]` is not a valid expression.

Comment: @LatinUnit, what's [wrong] with this place? The "intended" use of this site is not to answer your question. It's to answer the question you have *for others*.  If others can't see your original problem when they search for your question months later, they won't be helped by the answer(s).  Thus, I understand Roman B.'s objections. However, since my answer is so generic to shell questions in general ("quote liberally"), I don't see my response as egregious. Your code isn't required for future users to gain value from the response, IMO.

Comment: Tanktalus, how can i make the code read from the second line so that i dont get the message "Fully name is not fully enrolled" i tried with cat $file | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 this is how i usually fetch second lines from any text file. but the script must carry out the operation from the second file always. i started bash 2 days ago

Comment: I wrote a script that was plagued by this error thank you for the "use quotes liberally" I think I'll print it out in **BOLD** and affix it to my monitor