# Too many arguments in find

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

read DIR
read SEARCH

if [ `find $DIR -type f -exec grep $SEARCH /dev/null {} \;` ]; then
    echo "Find"
fi
```

What is wrong in this code? I have an error: too many arguments

Comment: Probably your `DIR` and `SEARCH` have values that are surprising to `find`.

Comment: Picking up on @Bex's comment, perhaps you could show the results of `echo`ing `DIR` and `SEARCH` before the `if`?

Comment: Recommend you quote around `$DIR` and `$SEARCH` to protect whitespace, eg: `find "$DIR" -type f...`

Comment: Don't use [ this way.  Just do `if find ... | grep -q .; then`

Comment: Do you want to print the results of the `find` or just that it found  a match? For the second case you should add a `-quit` option to find so it terminates without looking further.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332742/bash-too-many-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` or `[[` or `test` aren't a part of `if` shell structure but are commands which are provided to do comparisons.

You could try something like :

```
#!/bin/bash

read DIR
read SEARCH

[[ $(find "$DIR" -type f -exec grep "$SEARCH" {} \;) ]] && echo "Find"
# or
[[ -n $(find "$DIR" -type f -exec grep "$SEARCH" {} \;) ]] && echo "Find"
# or
[[ $(find "$DIR" -type f -exec grep "$SEARCH" {} \;) != "" ]] && echo "Find"
```

You could also try :

```
if [[ $(find "$DIR" -type f -exec grep "$SEARCH" {} \;) ]]; then
    echo "Find"
fi
```

Otherwise, do not forget the redirection operator before /dev/null.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the test all together ( that is the `[ ... ]`):

```
if find "$DIR" -type f -print0 | xargs --null grep -q "$SEARCH"
then
    echo "Find"
fi
```

The `find "$DIR" will execute and the results will be passed to`xargs`. This will give the`grep -q` statement the files you're passing.

The result of this statement will be the exit status of the **last** command in the pipe which is the `grep`. If `grep` finds what you're searching for, it will return an exit code of `0`. Otherwise, it'll return an exit code of non-zero. The `if` will pick this up, and will execute the `if` part of the statement if `grep` returned a zero.

The only issue is that `xargs` may execute `grep` more than once, and you'll get the status of the last `grep`. However, if that happened, then using `$(...)` will fail anyway.

Comment: +1 for recommending not to use `[ ... ]` and for using `xargs` to have the overall command reflect the outcome of `grep`; `find`'s `-print0` and `GNU grep`'s `--null` are not POSIX-compliant, but if you use `-0` instead of `--null`, it'll work on FreeBSD/OSX too; that said: if you terminate `-exec` with `+` rather than `\;`, it seems that `grep`'s exit code IS passed through, so `xargs` is not needed; also: see my answer for a pure `grep` (also not POSIX-compliant) alternative.

Answer (score 1):

**In GENERAL**:

- Always **double-quote variable references** to protect them from word-splitting and other shell expansions.
- **To create a conditional based on the exit code of a command, you do NOT need `[...]` or `[[ ... ]]`, simply use the command AS IS.**

Example: To test if any `*.txt` file in the current folder contains the word `needle`, you could use:

```
if grep -q "needle" *.txt; then # ...
```

Note: The `-q` suppresses `grep`'s output; in general, use redirection to suppress unwanted output, such as `&> /dev/null`.

---

**SPECIFICALLY**:

`find`'s exit code, when combined with `-exec` and terminator `\;`, only indicates whether `find` *itself* was invoked successfully, but does NOT reflect the outcome of the commands invoked with `-exec`. Thus, the overall command will NOT reflect whether `grep` succeeded or not.

If you want to use `find`, **be sure to terminate your `-exec` command with `+` rather than `\;`** - this apparently ensures that the exit code of the command invoked is passed through (verified with `GNU find 4.4.2` and the FreeBSD `find` version from OS X 10.9.2). With `+`, `-exec` acts similar to `xargs` (by default): the specified command is invoked *once* with *all* matching paths (unless all matching paths don't fit on a single command line).

```
if find "$DIR" -type f -exec grep -q "$SEARCH" {} + ; then # note the `-q`, `+`
  echo "Found."
fi
```

However, in the specific case at hand, **you may get away with just  `grep` itself**: 
*some* `grep` implementations (e.g., GNU `grep` (Linux) and FreeBSD `grep` (OSX)) have **option `-r` (alias: `-R`)**, which searches the specified input *directories recursively* (use `--include <glob>` and `--exclude <glob>` to filter by filename pattern):

```
if grep -q -r "$SEARCH" "$DIR"; then
  echo "Found."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run:

```
if [ `find $DIR -type f -exec grep $SEARCH /dev/null {} \;` ]; then
```

the standard output from `find`/`grep` is split into words and each word becomes an argument to the `[` command.  The POSIX version of the  [`[` or `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) command has rigid ideas about what it should accept, and the output from your command almost inevitably does not match those ideas, so you get the 'too many arguments' error message.

It isn't entirely clear what you want to do, but you've been given numerous ideas by other people.  My best guess is that you need:

```
if find "$DIR" -type f -exec grep "$SEARCH" /dev/null {} +
then echo "Found"
else echo "Not found"
fi
```

Note that I've used double quotes around `"$DIR"` and `"$SEARCH"`; this avoids nasty surprises.

Your use of `/dev/null` to ensure the file names are listed is a trick I use too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to just run `find $DIR -type f -exec grep $SEARCH /dev/null {} \;` with `DIR` and `SEARCH` set and see what the output is like. Probably it's quite long, and there are certain limits on command-line lengths. Since you seem to just check that the output is not empty, there is certainly a way of checking that without putting the whole string on the command line - you might be able to just chekc the return code of `find`, or as a quick and dirty solution, count the bytes and check if there are more than zero:

```
if  [ `find $DIR -type f -exec grep $SEARCH /dev/null {} \; | wc --bytes` -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Find"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer more about your problem than the original question (as the other answers do address the problem(s) in your question).

It seems you want to prompt the user for a directory to search and a pattern to find in the files that are in the directory. For this, `find` is useless as `grep` can search recursively in a directory already.

I don't really know *what* you want to do eventually with this (maybe you should have specified this, so that [we don't answer about Y when your original problem is X](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem)).

So assuming your problem is<sup>1</sup>:

> How can I prompt a user for a directory and a pattern, and determine whether this pattern is found in at least one of the files contained in the directory (and subdirectories). I don't want to know in which file the pattern is found, only whether it is there or not.

(I'm assuming this is your problem, because this is what your code seems to do in your OP).

To answer this problem:

```
IFS= read -rp 'Enter a directory: ' dir
IFS= read -rp 'Enter a pattern: ' search
if grep -Rq -- "$search" "$dir"; then
    echo "Pattern found"
else
    echo "Pattern not found"
fi
```

By the way this will be much more efficient than any other `find` method that don't use the `-quit` after the first found file, since `grep` with the `-q` option will exit immediately after finding the first match.

---

<sup>1</sup>It would have been better to state your problem X first, and then show what you attempted (i.e., Y), so that we have a clear picture of both what you want to achieve and how you tried to achieve it. This is a general advice I can give you about asking questions!