# Bash recursion: Save directory tree to text file

Tags: bash, shell, recursion, directory

I've been trying to learn bash, and I also have a large music folder containing artists' names and albums that I would like to backup to a text file. For example:

```
Arist1
    Album1
        Side A
        Side B
    Album2
Artist2
    Album1
```

The script that I have so far works on small directories and looks like this:

```
treesave (){ path="$1" indent=$2

cd "$path"
for i in *
do
    if [ -d ${i} ]; then
        printf "%${indent}s%s\n" " " "${i}"
        (treesave "${i}" $(( $indent + 4 )))
    fi
done
}
```

To save to a text file, I do
`(treesave path indent) >> outfile.txt`.

However, when I run this on my large music, I get an similarly large list of these errors:

```
-bash: [: too many arguments
-bash: [: Item: binary operator expected
```

Like I said, this works on small directories, so I wonder: Is my music library too large to recur through? It has less than a thousand artists. If I have to I can whip this up with python, but this is more a bash exercise than anything.

Also, as an aside, can someone explain the way/reason_why enclosing the command in parentheses is so crucial and why it keeps my shell cwd from changing after the function is done running?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: When I redirect the function to a txt file, about a quarter of the artist subdirectories get saved properly..

Comment: By way of debugging, I recommend that you try `echo "$i" > /dev/stderr` after your `do` statement. Run your program per usual, see what comes up on the console before the program fails.

Comment: To your aside, enclosing the command in parens runs it in a subshell. The `cd` applies to the subshell and its subshells, not to the parent shell.

Comment: `()` creates a sub-shell and the `cd` only affects that sub-shell and not the parent shell. You can actually define a function with `()` instead of `{}` and then the function will always run in a sub-shell automatically.

Comment: Any filename with a space will be seen as the test `[` binary as more than one string (since you didn't quote the `${i}` variable expansion and cause that error. Quote your variables.

Comment: @Politank-Z , This echoes everything in the current directory without a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: Too many arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332742/bash-too-many-arguments)